# Quais são os tipos de sujeitos nesta frase interrogativa?

Tags: sujeito, análise-morfossintática

Em frases interrogativas às vezes me confundo ao definir o tipo de sujeito da oração. Por exemplo na frase:

> ***"É para eu comer, professora?"***
>
> Quais seriam os sujeitos da oração fazendo uma **análise morfossintática completa**?

A análise do seguinte período composto é interessante, porém, não é uma interrogação e me causou menos confusão.

"É preciso amar as pessoas."

Analisando o primeiro verbo e seu complemento, "é" seria verbo de ligação e "preciso" seria predicativo do sujeito.

O que é preciso? "Amar as pessoas". Logo, Oração Subordinada Substantiva Subjetiva contendo o verbo amar.

Amar está no infinitivo com um sentido genérico, então, nessa oração, o sujeito é indeterminado.

Mas na frase que apresentei inicialmente, não consegui identificar as estruturas sintáticas.

Comment: O verbo ser nesse caso é impessoal.

Answer (score 1):

Sujeito é sempre aquele que realiza a ação. Nessa frase, quem irá realizar a ação de "comer" é "Eu", logo "Eu" é o sujeito.

Comment: para eu, não pode ser sujeito.

Comment: Podemos converter a frase e facilitar o entendimento. Digamos que, ao invés de "É para eu comer, professora?", eu dissesse "Professora, eu devo comer?", ou até mesmo "Professora, eu posso comer?". "para", "devo" ou "posso" acompanham o verbo, não o sujeito. O sujeito da ação de "dever comer" ou de "poder comer" continua sendo "Eu".

Comment: Bem confuso, certo? Sujeito preposicionado? Talvez... se na verdade a preposição "para" introduzir uma oração reduzida de infinitivo. Se "eu" não é sujeito, tem função sintática de complemento e deveria ser oblíquo. E aí, @Lambie, o que você acha?

Comment: @EvandroTeixeira, para ficar mais visível a conversão da frase poderia ser "Professora, é para eu comer?". Vou editar a questão apenas para sugerir uma análise morfossintática completa. Assim o caso fica melhor explicado.

Comment: A frase dada é português "popular".  E, o verbo *ser* aqui está sendo usado como infinito não flexionado e impessoal, do tipo: É proibido conversar durante a aula.

Comment: @Lambie Você diz que é português informal porque tem algum erro gramatical? Qual seria? Aguardo uma análise sintática completa para elucidar quais são os sujeitos e seus complementos.

Comment: @zewill Não, fala popular não tem erro. Só não é norma culta.

Comment: Bem-vindo, Evandro! Mesmo que Lambie te tenha provado errado, és muitíssimo bem-vindo aqui! E qualquer contribuição benigna tua será bem-vinda.

Answer (score 1):

Frases como "é preciso [verbo] **são impessoais**. Ou seja,
não tem sujeito. *É preciso terminar o trabalho agora.*

Que nem a canção e poesia de Fernando Pessoa (o melhor poeta da língua portuguesa!!)

Navegar é preciso, Viver não é preciso.
Sem inversão, dá: é preciso navegar.

[Só português](https://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/morf/morf69.php)

O infinitivo impessoal é usado quando apresenta uma ideia vaga, genérica, **sem se referir a um sujeito determinado;**

**Exemplos:**
**Querer é poder.**
Fumar prejudica a saúde.
**É proibido colar cartazes neste muro.**

Outro elemento importante na frase ou outra maneira de ver o assunto:

"*É para eu comer, professora?*" que seria *uma fala popular* (não é normal culta), não segue a regra do impessoal exatamente. Então, deixa aberta a possibilidade de ser analisada como **uma elipse**:

[elipse](https://www.todamateria.com.br/figura-de-linguagem-elipse/)

> A elipse é uma figura de linguagem que está na categoria de figuras de
> sintaxe (ou de construção). Isso porque ela está relacionada com a
> construção sintática dos enunciados.
>
> **Ela é utilizada para omitir termos numa sentença que não forem
> mencionados anteriormente. No entanto, esses termos são facilmente
> identificáveis pelo interlocutor.**

É para eu comer, professora?
Possibilidades:
**Esse biscoito** é para eu comer, professora?
**Esse prato de feijão** e arroz é para eu comer, professora?

Nestes casos, o sujeito seria: esse biscoito ou esse prato.
Isso se chama um sujeito elíptico:

> Sujeito determinado elíptico (oculto ou desinencial):
>
> O sujeito será classificado como determinado elíptico (existem outras
> nomenclaturas, sujeito oculto ou sujeito desinencial) quando ele não
> for apresentando de maneira explícita na oração. Ele poderá ser
> reconhecido por meio da desinência verbal ou do contexto em que a
> oração é empregada.

[sujeito elíptico](https://brasilescola.uol.com.br/gramatica/tipos-sujeito.htm)

Comment: Ainda não entendi porque a frase não pode ser considerada norma culta, já que me parece estar correta e completa gramaticalmente. Ou toda frase com sujeito elíptico é considerada fala popular?

Comment: Outra coisa, o período em questão seria composto? São dois sujeitos a se analisar?

Comment: Já disse o que penso. Culto e não culto não depende da gramaticalidade. https://ead.unisc.br/blog/linguagem-coloquial